# I need to show that a function is a family of solutions of a differential equation, but not a general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that $y=({1\over 4} x^2 + c^2)$ is a family of solutions of ${dy\over dx} = xy^{1/2}$ but it is not the general solution since $y=0$ is also a solution which is not a member of the family of solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Plug $y=1/4 x^2 + c^2$ into the differential equation, check that it holds. Plug $y=0$ into the equation, check that it holds. Do you get any particular difficulty doing this?

Comment: I meant the first one

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a solution for any $c$. Should the differential equation have  been $\frac{dy}{dx}=y^{1/2}$ instead? Then at least $c=0$ produces a solution (for $x\ge 0$).

Comment: Nop, the D.E is $xy^{1/2}$

Answer (score 1):

For $y \neq 0$ we have that

$$\frac{dy}{y^{\frac{1}{2}}}=xdx \Rightarrow y^{-\frac{1}{2}}dy=xdx \Rightarrow \frac{y^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{x^2}{2}+c \Rightarrow y^{\frac{1}{2}}=x^2+2c \Rightarrow \dots$$

For $y=0$ we see that the equality holds.